# How to integrate the Skype with the Checkmk Server which is running in AWS instance

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, skype-bots, check-mk

I have a Separate server in AWS with the Checkmk running over it and i now want to integrate with SKYPE with the CheckMk so that the alerts can be seen in the Skype . is there any possible ways for doing this ?

There is no documents for this integration. needed help

Answer (score 0):

There is no Skype integration for Checkmk, but starting with Checkmk 2.2 you will have native Microsoft Teams support. You might want to look into that.